# Getting the url of the current page in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to log all requests that are made for each page that I load. Here are the `manifest.json` and `background.js` files for it.

`manifest.json:`

```
{
  "name": "Requests",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Log Requests",
  "permissions": ["webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

`background.js:`

```
var url = ''

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    url = tabs[0].url;
});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {

    console.log("Request for " + url + ':  --> ' + info.url);
  },
  // filters
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
  },
  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking"]);
```

The issue that I have is that the `url` parameter inside `background.js` always contains `chrome://extension/` no matter which page I am loading. I do not understand why this could be happening. I tried to use `window.location` to give me the current url, but thats returning the same  value as well. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Why do you think it would change? You only set `url` once, and never change it. So, it never changes.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the answer Makyen. My understanding was that `chrome.tabs.query` would be fired each time a new link was loaded. I tried to do it via `chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function (details) { 
 url = details.url; 
 });` but thats not returning the correct url every time. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Just did it by nesting the `chrome.tabs.query` method inside the `callback` for `onBeforeRequest` and it works. I hope the approach is right.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. Create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem. When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for letting me know. Just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's a solution that works. The only thing I did was to put `chrome.tabs.query` method inside the callback for `onBeforeRequest` so that its triggered each time a request is received (and hence the url gets updated as well).

```
var url = ''

var callbackOnRequest = function(info) {

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        if (tabs[0] != undefined){
                url = tabs[0].url;
            }

    });

    console.log("Request for " + url + ':  --> ' + info.url);
}
var filters = {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
};

var extraInfoSpec = ["blocking"];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callbackOnRequest, filters, extraInfoSpec);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get each request url by  chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT function in ***background.js***

```
   chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
   function(tabs){
      alert(tabs[0].url);
   }
);
```

Comment: That is always the location of the background page.